# How to separate in vue.js entered value and displayed value in input[type=text]?

Tags: vue.js

Example:

```
<span class='prefix'>+{{ prefix }}</span>
<input type='tel' v-model='phone'>
```

What should be displayed

```
When phone === '790012345678', it is actually
prefix = '7'
phone = '90012345678'
```

And displayed accordingly

```
<span class='prefix'>+7</span>
<input type='tel' value='90012345678'>
```

When user removes value from input, prefix is removed too.

Problem (jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4qqza69k/48/)

```
I use watcher for `phone`.
When user changes something inside `input` watcher must update value for `phone`, but this way it is triggered again and it receives updated (incorrect) value.
```

Scenarios:

1. Phone equals 7-100-200-30-40
   prefix = +7, phone = 1002003040
2. Phone equals 7
   prefix = +7, phone = ''
3. Phone equals 7123
   prefix = +7, phone = 123
4. Phone is empty
   prefix = '', phone = ''

Problem: how to exclude prefix from input without triggering updates?

Comment: Does not really answer your question, but for your particular use case, you may be interested by https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ and its vuejs version https://github.com/jrainlau/vue-cleave

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rewrite `v-model` into more explicit `v-on + v-bind` pair and listen to `input` for a phone number, while calculating prefix and the rest part separately:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    prefix: '',
    phone: '', // full phone number
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput: function(e) {
      if (e.target.value === '') this.prefix = '';
      if (this.prefix !== '') {
       this.phone = this.prefix + e.target.value;
      } else {
       const v = e.target.value;
        this.phone = v;
        this.prefix = v.slice(0,1);
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    withoutPrefix: function() {
      return (this.prefix !== '') ? this.phone.slice(1) : ''
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span class='prefix'>+{{ prefix }}</span>
  <input type='tel' @input="handleInput" :value="withoutPrefix">
  <p>Phone: {{ phone }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not exactly work cause I'm being a bit confused by your example, but I think one way is to use computed getter/setter instead.

```js
data() {
    return {
        hiddenInputValue: ''
    }
},
computed: {
    inputValue: {
        get() {
            return this.hiddenInputValue;
        },
        set(val) {
            // do something with the input value...
            this.hiddenInputValue = // assign a modified version of the input value...
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to do something with that, but check my comment. It's probably a better solution.